# Make domain module pure kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dns, dagger-hilt

I developed a modular android application, but i have a problem in making domain module pure kotlin. I mean, i want my domain module be a kotlin (or java) library, not an android library.
everything is ok till i use hilt to inject my repository interface into my usecase.
Here i face some error.because hilt is an android library and i shouldn't use it. But i need it.
as you can see :

```
import com.example.domain_article.repository.ArticleRepository
import javax.inject.Inject

class GetArticleListLocalUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val articleRepository: ArticleRepository) {
    operator fun invoke() = articleRepository.getArticleListLocal()
}
```

here we have @Inject which belongs to hilt (dagger) and if i remove hilt dependency from gradle of domain module i will get an error.

what should i do to make my domain pure kotlin and hilt?

Comment: As for dependency injection, You can use Kotlin DI library **Koin** instead of Dagger Hilt.

Comment: `@Inject` doesn't belongs to hilt (dagger). it belongs to `javax inject` library and you can use it without dagger depedency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this before,

You can import the following:

```
import javax.inject.Inject
```

This would give `@inject` without adding dagger-hilt to your domain module.

> **@Inject** belongs to javax inject as said by @IR42 in comments

And in order to use this library you can

```
implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
```